# What does 'the death of his yet' mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I was reading an English version of The Romance of Three Kingdoms (if anyone cares), and I came across this phrase:

> I will be the death of his yet!

I have no clue about what this means. It might be an idiom or 'yet' has a rare meaning. I imagined it could be a noun but dictionaries only show 'yet' as adverb or conjunction. Any idea of what it is?

Edit: Thanks, KillingTime. If anyone reads this, it was a typo, 'him' instead of 'his', so the phrase is

> 'I will be the death of him yet'

, which should mean 'I will ruin his life from now on'.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is conceded to be merely a typo.

Answer (score 1):

In https://www.idioms.online/be-the-death-of/ the definition notes that the phrase can be used literally to refer to actual death, or it can be used as a hyperbole—exaggeration—emphasizing frustration, worry, extra work, or whatever. Sometimes even humorously.

Comment: Basic; OP asks about the particular example. Probably a typo (but perhaps poor grammar).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It would certainly not be poor grammar (nor a typo) if the sentence were referring to ***his*** *dog*.

Comment: @Jason Bassford And if an italicisation has been missed by OP, it might mean that the speaker is trying to make singular _their_ mandatory. But the question lacks sufficient detail for a decent answer (and is _very probably_ off-topic as a mere typo).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I wrote some details in the replies if you are interested